# restful wcf service makes a client callback whenever there is update in a server

Tags: c#, javascript, c++, wcf, rest

I am writing a WCF RESTFUL service over a c++ console application. client uses a browser and connects to that c++ application via my restful wcf service,Whenever my wcf service gets an update from c++ application, I need to send that status update to a browser client without the browser refreshing the page. How can I do this? please help me out. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do this with WCF and the WebHttpBinding (REST) binding. Alternatively you can use a WCF binding that supports callbacks or take a look at running SignalR in an ASP.net WEB.API service.

Note the WCF bindings that support callbacks (duplex) are:

NetTcpBinding
NetNamedPipeBinding
WSDualHttpBinding

Comment: Thank you Eric for the reply. So can I use WSDualHttpBinding? If I use that it will not be restful service?

Comment: What do you consider a RESTful service?

Comment: user uses a browser's uri to contact our service rather than a soap message. I am sorry if I am wrong, I am new to wcf service. please help me.

Comment: You can use ASP.Net WEB API or WCF WebHttpBinding to avoid SOAP and use either JSON or XML, or whatever else if you want to customize. The problem is with callbacks (pushing back to the client). Neither of those two do that, in my answer I recommend SignalR and have the web page use the SignalR javascript library.

Comment: Thanks a lot Eric, you made me understood what's going on. So I am going to try signalR, can you please give some resources which mimics my situation?

Comment: I would need more information on what exactly your doing in the browser, but if you go over the following getting started sections you should be able to draw your own conclusions: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/introduction-to-signalr