# Sending progress information from WCF Rest services?

Tags: c#, rest, wcf

We have developed a web app based on HTML5, Javascript, and WCF Rest. The user will upload files to the server using WCF Rest Stream. I am showing a progress for file upload in HTML, the problem that I noticed is that when the progress says it's 100%, the WCF call is not completed yet as the file is still writing to the disk. So I was thinking of sending progress from WCF to HTML. Is there a way for me to send the information from a WCF Rest application to the HTML page? I have heard about the following options

a) **Web Sockets** - The problem is that I have to open a dedicated endpoint to my server which my employer has rejected it.

b) **SignalR** - The problem that I faced is that the message that is received by HTML is a delayed message. I am receiving the message even after the WCF call is completed which is not the accurate answer to my question.

What I want to know is, are there any other options that we can use to send information to HTML using WCF Rest services.

Thanks,
Jollyguy

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618723/restful-wcf-service-makes-a-client-callback-whenever-there-is-update-in-a-server

Comment: I'm curious as to this dedicated endpoint requirement you mention. Web sockets uses HTTP. If you are serving your HTML5 app and have a WCF REST service then you already are using HTTP.

That aside, SignalR also uses WebSockets by default, unless you use one of the fallback transports, which also all use HTTP.